# Consulta sobre SQL INNER JOIN SELECT TOP 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

Tengo la siguiente cuestión: en una tabla tengo un **`ID`** que se relaciona con la otra tabla, pero la tabla hija tiene varios **`ID`** de la tabla padre entonces al momento de hacer el **`INNER JOIN`** me trae **N** registros. Estoy intentando hacer un **`SELECT TOP 1`** en el **`JOIN`** pero no he tenido éxito.

En la tabla **B** tengo N veces el **`ID_A`**, pero quiero que solo me traiga el primero.

```
SELECT * FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON B.ID_A = A.ID_A
```

Entonces si hago la consulta de manera normal me trae varias veces el mismo registro pues en la tabla B existen varios registros asociados a ese ID.

Entonces probé con esto:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON B.ID_A = (SELECT TOP 1 ID_A FROM B WHERE ID_A = A.ID_A)
```

Pero sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado, me sigue arrojando el mismo numero de resultados que la primer consulta. ¿Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependiendo de los datos que necesites de la tabla **B** puedes hacer algo así:

```
SELECT A.*,
       B.*
       FROM TablaA A
       INNER JOIN ( SELECT ID, OtroCampo
                           FROM TablaB
                           GROUP BY ID, OtroCampo
                   ) B
                   ON B.ID_A = A.ID_A
```

Comment: De esa forma si me trae solo un registro, pero si quiero traer más campos me marca error, únicamente me deja hacerlo con el campo ID_A

Comment: Olvídalo, estaba haciendo referencia a otra tabla XD, tu respuesta me ha servido correctamente. Muchas gracias ya llevaba como 20 minutos dándole vueltas.

Comment: Ok, me alegro te haya servido